# Como criar um GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Os exemplos que vi na net nenhum funcionaram, ou eram muito personalizados.
Quero apenas uma tabela simples, com 4 colunas que vão ser preenchidas com dados de um bd.
O mesmo vai ficar dentro de um modal simples:

```
<div class="modal fade open" id="modalVersao" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header" >
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Gerenciar Versões"></asp:Label></h4>
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-body">

         <!-- Quero o GRID aqui -->

                                                                                     </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    //Botoes
                                </div>
```

Comment: Voce nao pode usar um DataGridView e setar o seus dados como DATASOURCE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Você pode concluir sua tarefa facilmente com uma `table HTML` e um `foreach` (ou `for` se preferir).
Ainda pode fazer isto com o `asp:gridview` ou `asp:repeater` (também utilizando `table` no caso do *repeater*).
Um intermediário entre os dois é o `asp:ListView`.

Um exemplo com o `Repeater`:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Código</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
                <td>Descrição</td>
                <td>Categoria</td>
                <td>Preço Unitário (R$)</td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Id") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Nome") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Descricao") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Categoria") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("PrecoUnitario") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Foo</td>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>FOO</td>
                <td>fOO</td>
                <td>ooF</td>
            </tr>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

No C#:

```
List<Produto> produtos = ProdutoService.GetProdutos();
this.Repeater.DataSource = produtos;
this.Repeater.DataBind();
```

Sobre o `Repeater`, você pode encontrar mais informações aqui: http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Outro recurso útil:

- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart

Espero que isto o ajude, mas fique a vontade para compartilhar mais informações a respeito.

Comment: Pode ser um exemplo com repeater e um table, a persistencia é Entity framework, ja tenho os dados. quero listar ,ID, nome, etc, são 5 campos. Um espaço para um checkbox seria interessante., se puder postar um exemplo ai agradeço, vlw.

Comment: Desculpe a demora cara. Acabei não conseguindo fazer em casa. Fiz um exemplo bem simples e editei a resposta. Veja se o ajuda. Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado desculpa a demora tambem...

Comment: No problem. Espero que o exemplo tenha ajudado... Se precisar de outros avise. Valeu!